# PLL with variable pulse widths

Tags: pll

Is there a way to construct a PLL cicruit which locks on to an input signal's phase but provides an output signal with different duty cycles?

Comment: Not sure why you want to use a PLL, simply triggering an adjustable monostable multivibrator from the input signal may do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, PLL to 256x the signal frequency and feed that into a counter. Use the source clock to reset the counter.